# Relation between reflexivity and FPP

Tags: functional-analysis

It is known that if $X$ be a Banach space and $X$ be reflexive then $X$ isomorphic to a Banach space with FPP. I have two questions 
1: Is there a reflexive Banach space but does not FPP?

2:It is known that FPP is a metric property, and is not preserved if the norm is replaced by an equivalent one and  a Hilbert space $H$. If a Banach  space  $X$ isomorphic with a Hilbert space $H$ , does $X$ admits FPP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, these are open problems. See [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFEQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1007%252Fs40065-012-0054-x.pdf&ei=hSMkU-ybMIeCygHTuoDYBg&usg=AFQjCNHH8o37JabKmUnBtk_IshycO_3Ifg&bvm=bv.62922401,d.aWc&cad=rja).

Comment: I think if we  find out a suitable upper bounded for Banach -Mazur distance then maybe we could answer this questions

Comment: @DavidMitra I think OP doesn't know that comments can't get a bounty. So please post that comment as answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2012 at least, these problems remain open, according to [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFEQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1007%252Fs40065-012-0054-x.pdf&ei=hSMkU-ybMIeCygHTuoDYBg&usg=AFQjCNHH8o37JabKmUnBtk_IshycO_3Ifg&bvm=bv.62922401,d.aWc&cad=rja), which is a survey about what is known regarding question 2.

Comment: Dear David Mitra may I have your Email address, thanks